# react-native-elements Checkbox title styling

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to style the **checkbox title** text from react native:

```
   <CheckBox
        checked={this.state.checked}
        onPress={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked})}
        containerStyle={styles.checkBox}
        title='Complete task'
        fontStyle={styles.checkBoxText}
      />

 checkBoxText: {
 color: '#4a4a4a',
 fontWeight: 'normal',
 },
```

but I'm getting nothing. Is there anyway to style this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `textStyle` instead of `fontStyle`. Docs here: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html#textstyle

Answer (score 0):

For those who cannot change some title attributes, add `title={<Text style={{}}>Hello</Text>}`